# c# error cannot convert collection.generitic.lists to classes

Tags: c#

I want to add a outcome from a method into a list but is says:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FontysFood.Classes.VoedingswaardenList>' to 'FontysFood.Classes.VoedingswaardenList'
```

Here is the source code for this part of the code:

```
    public void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string uuid;
        try
        {
            VoedingswaardenOproep Oproep = new VoedingswaardenOproep(uuid = (dataGrid.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(dataGrid.SelectedItem) as TextBlock).Text);
            VoedingswaardenList OproepProductList = Oproep.GetWinkelmandjeInfo();
            MainWindow.AlleVoed.Add(OproepProductList);
            MainWindow.Details.DGVoedingswaarden.Items.Refresh();
            MessageBox.Show(OproepProductList.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: We need to see a bit more code than this, especially since it's in a foreign language.

Comment: I added the more code!

Comment: Code still seems to be missing any reference to the List object that's throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm reading this right, you're trying to `Add` a collection, but you can only add single items using `Add`, not the whole collection. Try setting the `Items` property if present.

```
MainWindow.AlleVoed.Items = OproepProductList
```

or

```
MainWindow.AlleVoed.ItemSource = OproepProductList
```

or maybe

```
MainWindow.AlleVoed.AddRange(OproepProductList);
```

Depending on what `AlleVoed` actually is. The point is you need to use a method that accepts a collection of objects, or you can write a loop to add them all one by one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the code and the error message, `Oproep.GetWinkelmandjeInfo()` returns a list of `VoedingswaardenList`, but you try to assign it to a non-list type variable. I assume you need to change the type of `OproepProductList` to `List<VoedingswaardenList>` like so:

```
List<VoedingswaardenList> OproepProductList = Oproep.GetWinkelmandjeInfo();
```

After that, JSteward's suggestions might apply.

Alternatively, change the `GetWinkelmandjeInfo` method to just return a `VoedingswaardenList` instead of a list of these. That really depends on the semantics of your program, which is hard to understand in a foreign language.